# Android: Get PHP Result into a String in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I have a PHP-File that get me the last ID from a MySQL Database.
The File result is 42.

If i write this in Android (Kotlin):

```
var lastID: String? = null
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val url = "https://uwbeinternational.org/android/getLastSPLId.php"

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url,
            { response ->
                lastID = response
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "ID Lautet: " + lastID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            },
            { lastID = "Fail!" })

        queue.add(stringRequest)
```

It works and th Toast show "42" to me. But, how i can use the "lastID" as String outside of the Function? If i try to write:

```
    var lastID: String? = null
            val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
            val url = "https://uwbeinternational.org/android/getLastSPLId.php"

            // Request a string response from the provided URL.
            val stringRequest = StringRequest(
                Request.Method.GET, url,
                { response ->
                    lastID = response
                },
                { lastID = "Fail!" })

            queue.add(stringRequest)
Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "ID Lautet: " + lastID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

The Result (lastID) show "null". What can or should i do to get the right response "lastID" with "42" to a outside String/Variable?

Comment: Although this is coming from a PHP server, it appears to be unrelated to PHP from a problem perspective, so I’m removing that tag. To the actual problem, I don’t know this specific problem, but it appears to be a scoping and/or concurrency one.

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion, you need change your PHP result, from HTML to [REST API](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-simple-rest-api-in-php--cms-37000) with JSON Data.

In Android you must make HTTP Client, you can use [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) or [Fast Android Networking](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking). if you like [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley) just go on

Comment: In my PHP File i have echo encode_json($response);. Maybe, i will try with retrofit now.

Comment: nice, i'm trying your link the result is HTML, you can learn how to make REST API using PHP in this link https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-simple-rest-api-in-php--cms-37000

Answer (score 0):

You are displaying your toast before Volley got the change to communicate with php and get a response.

Keep your Toast where it was.

Or only toast after you got the response.

For a test keep both toasts and you will see.

Comment: Hmm . I dont understand the Logic about this. When i set the Toast directly under the Line "lastID = response", the Result was correctly 42. If i use the Toast after Volley, the Result is "null". Volley give me a correct Response, but i cant use lastID after oder outside volley.

Comment: Did you do the test with two toasts? Which comes first?

Comment: You should have adapted the code in your post. Not messing up with code in a comment. Well... why dont you comment...? You now know the reason. How are you gonna adapt your code now?